# search person table for a given name

Tags: mysql

i have a person table in yu db where i store firstname and lastname separately. How could I do a search if firstname was "John" and lastname was "Doe" and I searched for "John D"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table where concat_ws(' ',name,surname) like 'John D%'
```

Comment: aren't you missing a parameter for concat_ws?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(lastname, ' ', firstname)) LIKE 'john d%'
   OR LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE 'john d%'
```

You should also ensure that you convert all your strings to lower case or do case insensitive search.

---

Edit: if firstname or lastname can be null, then it will be better to use CONCAT_WS instead of CONCAT.

Comment: So, how does your answer handle "middle name cases"?

Comment: This is good, although the OP might not want "John D" to match "David John", in which case you would only want the second clause of the OR. If both results are wanted, then this gets them.

Answer (score 0):

Split "John D" up into "John" and "D" and then use a query like:

SELECT * FROM person WHERE firstname="John" AND lastname LIKE "D%"

Comment: firstname / name could be in any order. How to handle middle name cases?

Comment: The OP specifically said that he wanted John Doe as a result for a search of "John D". That implies that the first name is first, and there is no mention of middle names in the question. Are you the one who downvoted my answer?

Comment: Where do you choose to split "John W Do" And why? Concatenating the database fields get around that problem whether middle name is stored within first or last name or even a third middlename field that can be as well concatenated. Nothing very important though, I agree.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought you were talking about a middle name in the database (which there could also be). If the search string is "John Paul van D" then there's no way to tell where it should be split. I agree that doing the concat on the database columns is much better and more robust.